# For each selected datagridview row send to richTextBox

Tags: c#

I need foreach selected datagridview1 rows to send specific cells into a richTextBox.

Here is what i'm trying:

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
                {
                 richTextBox1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
```

But it works only for first selected.

Comment: Instead of `dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0]`, use `item`? Also, don't use `=` but `+=` to not overwrite the textbox's text every iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each item you're resetting the contents of richTextBox1.

And in your foreach, you should use "item". Currently you're not using item, but always using the first row instead.

What you probably want is to append the text to the contents of the RichTextBox.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
    //Each foreach iteration, item will contain a different row.
    richTextBox1.Text += item.Cells[1].Value.ToString(); //Append the text of the current row
}
```

Note: something+=x is short for: something = something + x;